# Plotting 3d network graphs in plotly

Tags: javascript, html, graph, plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to plot a 3d network using plotly.js

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <script>
      var nodes = [
        { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
        { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 },
        { x: 2, y: 0, z: 2 },
        { x: 3, y: 1, z: 3 },
        { x: 4, y: 0, z: 4 }
      ];

      var edges = [
        { source: 0, target: 1 },
        { source: 1, target: 2 },
        { source: 2, target: 3 },
        { source: 3, target: 4 }
      ];

      var x = [];
      var y = [];
      var z = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        x.push(nodes[i].x);
        y.push(nodes[i].y);
        z.push(nodes[i].z);
      }

      var xS = [];
      var yS = [];
      var zS = [];
      var xT = [];
      var yT = [];
      var zT = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        xS.push(nodes[edges[i].source].x);
        yS.push(nodes[edges[i].source].y);
        zS.push(nodes[edges[i].source].z);
        xT.push(nodes[edges[i].target].x);
        yT.push(nodes[edges[i].target].y);
        zT.push(nodes[edges[i].target].z);
      }

      var traceNodes = {
        x: x, y: y, z: z,
        mode: 'markers',
        marker: { size: 12, color: 'red' },
        type: 'scatter3d'
      };

      var traceEdges = {
        x: [xS, xT],
        y: [yS, yT],
        z: [zS, zT],
        mode: 'lines',
        line: { color: 'red', width: 2},
        opacity: 0.8,
        type: 'scatter3d'
      };
      
      var layout = {
        margin: { l: 0, r: 0, b: 0, t: 0 }
      };

      Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [traceNodes, traceEdges], layout);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The nodes of the network are visible but the edges are not visible. Suggestions on
how to fix this issue will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how `traceEdges` is built. On each axis, there should be a list of (source, target) coordinates separated by a null value, ie. :

```
x: [source_0.x, target_0.x, null, source_1.x, target_1.x, null, ...]
```

We use null values to properly isolate each edge from the others and prevent chaining them all together (we want to draw a line between `source_0` and  `target_0`, but not between `target_0` and `source_1`).

So instead of having `[xS, xT]`, `[yS, yT]`, and `[zS, zT]` we will just have  `edge_x`, `edge_y`, and `edge_z`, defined as follows :

```js
const edge_x  = [];
const edge_y  = [];
const edge_z  = [];

for (var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
  const a = nodes[edges[i].source];
  const b = nodes[edges[i].target];
  edge_x.push(a.x, b.x, null);
  edge_y.push(a.y, b.y, null);
  edge_z.push(a.z, b.z, null);
}

const traceEdges = {
  x: edge_x,
  y: edge_y,
  z: edge_z,
  type: 'scatter3d',
  mode: 'lines',
  line: { color: 'red', width: 2},
  opacity: 0.8
};

// (rest of the code doesn't change)
```

Here is the output :

[image: plot]